# Is there a good XMPP (Jabber) library for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, xmpp

I have a few sensors plugged in and getting some data from them. I want to use XMPP protocol to push the sensor data to my main server. Is there a good XMPP library available which I can use?

Answer (score 1):

[Arduino-XMPP](https://github.com/adamvr/XMPPArduino) This depends on [Arduino-Base64](https://github.com/adamvr/arduino-base64) - This should be included before `XMPPClient.h` or added to your main library directory.

[Other Product specific XMPP Library.](http://fablab.ruc.dk/get-xmpp-protocol-on-arduino/)

[MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) Protocol.

[Yaler](https://www.yaler.net/)

Comment: only that I have already tried this library, there is only one contributor of this library and it has issues in configuration of server.